# Recursion over a mutable binary tree: `already borrowed: BorrowMutError`

Tags: memory-management, rust, borrowing

I'm beginning with a `Vec` of sorted nodes, then using this sorting to link these nodes together in a binary tree and then returning the base struct

```rust
// Test name
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Struct {
    parent: Option<Rc<RefCell<Struct>>>,
    superscript: Option<Rc<RefCell<Struct>>>,
    subscript: Option<Rc<RefCell<Struct>>>,
    height: u32,
    center: u32,
    symbols: VecDeque<u8>
}
```

Ending up with a binary tree formed by the above `Struct`s. At this point, these `Struct`s are uniquely owned, so I think I could convert from using `Rc<RefCell<Struct>>` to `RefCell<Struct>` (think `Box<Struct>` doesn't work due to internal mutability?), but I'm not sure how or if this helps with the problem I'm encountering.

After this, I need to iterate in a novel manner through the `Struct`s, and mutate the various `symbols` belonging to the various `Struct`s throughout the recursion, via calling `.pop_front()`.

My current implementation doing this leads to various instances of `thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError'`.

Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=636c93088f5a431d0d430d42283348f3

The function for it (please excuse the convoluted logic):

```rust
fn traverse_scripts(row: Rc<RefCell<Struct>>) {
    if let Some(superscript_row) = &row.borrow().superscript {
        if let Some(superscript_symbol) = superscript_row.borrow().symbols.front() {
            if let Some(current_row_symbol) = row.borrow().symbols.front()  {
                if superscript_symbol < current_row_symbol {
                    println!("^{{{}",*superscript_symbol);
                    superscript_row.borrow_mut().symbols.pop_front();
                    traverse_scripts(Rc::clone(superscript_row));
                }
            }
            else {
                println!("^{{{}",*superscript_symbol);
                superscript_row.borrow_mut().symbols.pop_front();
                traverse_scripts(Rc::clone(superscript_row));
            }
        }
    }

    if let Some(subscript_row) = &row.borrow().subscript {
        if let Some(subscript_symbol) = subscript_row.borrow().symbols.front() {
            if let Some(current_row_symbol) = row.borrow().symbols.front() {
                if subscript_symbol < current_row_symbol  {
                    print!("_{{{}",*subscript_symbol);
                    subscript_row.borrow_mut().symbols.pop_front();
                    traverse_scripts(Rc::clone(subscript_row));
                }
            }
            else {
                print!("_{{{}",*subscript_symbol);
                subscript_row.borrow_mut().symbols.pop_front();
                traverse_scripts(Rc::clone(subscript_row));
            }
        }
    }

    if let Some(current_row_symbol) = row.borrow().symbols.front()  {
        if let Some(parent_row) = &row.borrow().parent {
            if let Some(parent_symbol) = parent_row.borrow().symbols.front() {
                if current_row_symbol < parent_symbol {
                    print!(" {}",*current_row_symbol);
                    row.borrow_mut().symbols.pop_front();
                    traverse_scripts(Rc::clone(&row));
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print!(" {}",*current_row_symbol);
            row.borrow_mut().symbols.pop_front();
            traverse_scripts(Rc::clone(&row));
        }
    }

    if let Some(parent_row) = &row.borrow().parent {
        if let Some(parent_symbol) = parent_row.borrow().symbols.front() {
            print!("}} {}",*parent_symbol);
            row.borrow_mut().symbols.pop_front();
            traverse_scripts(Rc::clone(parent_row));
        } else {
            print!("}}");
            traverse_scripts(Rc::clone(parent_row));
        }
    }
}
```

I've considered using `Arc<Mutex<Struct>>` instead for the traversal, but given its not multi-threaded I don't think it's neccessary?

I imagine I might be missing a relatively simple idea here, I would really appreciate any help.

If I've missed anything in my question please drop a comment and I'll try to add it.

Comment: *At this point, these `Structs` are uniquely owned*: it's possible to make a tree with unique ownership, but this isn't it: each node may be owned by the parent links in its children, as well as by the child link in its parent. If you want to switch to `Box` you have to remove the parent links.

Comment: `Mutex` wouldn't help, either, BTW - the `lock` method works in the same way as `borrow_mut` on `RefCell`. So you'd end up with the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `borrow` or `borrow_mut` on a `RefCell`, a guard object (`Ref` or `RefMut`) is created that grants access to the inner value for as long as it exists. This guard will lock the `RefCell` until it goes out of scope and is destroyed. Let's look at a portion of `traverse_scripts`:

```
if let Some(superscript_row) = &row.borrow().superscript { // row is borrowed
    if let Some(superscript_symbol) = superscript_row.borrow().symbols.front() { // superscript_row is borrowed
        if let Some(current_row_symbol) = row.borrow().symbols.front() { // row is borrowed again
            if superscript_symbol < current_row_symbol {
                println!("^{{{}", *superscript_symbol);
                superscript_row.borrow_mut().symbols.pop_front(); // superscript_row is borrowed mutably (ERROR)
                traverse_scripts(Rc::clone(superscript_row)); // recursive call while row and superscript_row are borrowed (ERROR)
            }
        } else {
            println!("^{{{}", *superscript_symbol);
            superscript_row.borrow_mut().symbols.pop_front(); // superscript_row is borrowed mutably (ERROR)
            traverse_scripts(Rc::clone(superscript_row)); // recursive call while row and superscript_row are borrowed (ERROR)
        } // row is no longer borrowed twice
    } // superscript_row is no longer borrowed
} // row is no longer borrowed
```

In the first line, for example, `row.borrow()` returns a `Ref<Struct>`. This `Ref` can't be dropped immediately, because it's being borrowed during the `if let` body by `superscript_row`. So it stays alive that whole time -- until the final `}`.

This is a problem for recursively calling `traverse_scripts` because the `Struct` is borrowed during the *entire* recursive call. Any attempt to borrow the same `Struct` mutably deeper in the call stack will fail. (Borrowing it immutably does still work.)

In the second line `superscript_row` is borrowed. This has the same problem, but it also has a more immediate one: it's borrowed mutably later in the same function, even before hitting the recursive call. That `borrow_mut` can never succeed because `superscript_row` is always already borrowed at that point.

To fix both problems, we'll do two things:

1. Store each `Ref` or `RefMut` guard in a variable of its own and re-use that guard, instead of calling `borrow()` or `borrow_mut()` on the same variable again.
2. Before recursing, `drop` each of the still-living guards so that nothing is still borrowed inside the recursive call.

Here's what that section might look like rewritten:

```
{ // This scope will constrain the lifetime of row_ref
    let row_ref = row.borrow();
    if let Some(superscript_row) = &row_ref.superscript {
        let mut child = superscript_row.borrow_mut(); // use borrow_mut here because we know we'll need it later
        if let Some(superscript_symbol) = child.symbols.front() {
            if let Some(current_row_symbol) = row_ref.symbols.front() {
                if superscript_symbol < current_row_symbol {
                    println!("^{{{}", *superscript_symbol);
                    child.symbols.pop_front();
                    drop(child); // child is no longer needed, so drop it before recursing
                    // Since superscript_row borrows from row_ref, we must Rc::clone it before
                    // dropping row_ref so that we can still pass it to traverse_scripts.
                    let superscript_row = Rc::clone(superscript_row);
                    drop(row_ref); // row_ref is no longer needed, so drop it before recursing
                    traverse_scripts(superscript_row);
                }
            } else {
                println!("^{{{}", *superscript_symbol);
                child.symbols.pop_front();
                // see comments earlier
                drop(child);
                let superscript_row = Rc::clone(superscript_row);
                drop(row_ref);
                traverse_scripts(superscript_row);
            }
        }
    } // child is dropped here (if it wasn't already). superscript_row is no longer borrowed
} // row_ref is dropped here (if it wasn't already). row is no longer borrowed
```

[Full-program playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fc1b0e4d8a2129a251904480c29e9f9f).

This looks complicated because it is complicated. Traversing over a data structure while mutating it is a common source of bugs (in most languages, not just Rust). It looks like, in `traverse_scripts` at least, the only reason for needing mutation is to call `pop_front` on `symbols`, so if you can redesign the data structure such that only `symbols` is in a `RefCell`, you could do the traversal with only `&` references, which would be much easier. Another common approach is to write functions that return new data structures instead of mutating them in place.

Comment: Thank you! (After some restructuring of my logic, it works)

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light You can also make this code simpler by folding each nested `if let ... if ... else` into a single `if`, since the inner `if` and the outer `else` are identical: [see here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b0f04df86d701649c7f5da1621f45df5). There are some asymmetries in the code that might be logic bugs, which if fixed might also make it simpler. But I suspect the biggest bang for your buck is in changing how you store the nodes (for instance: a single `Vec<Struct>` with indices, rather than an ocean of `Rc`s).